#  Python define class in function, the class canbe access global

Tags: python, class

abc.py, how to create b() in class a ?

```
class a(object):
  bInst=b()

def start():
  class b(obj):
    pass

if __name=='__main__'
  start()
```

But how to using variable, Here is the codes, it report 'myCls' is not defined.

```
class a(obj):
   inst=myCls()

def start
    tSuiteN="myCls"
    exec('global tSuiteN')
    str="class {}(object): pass".format(tSuiteN)
    exec(str)
```

Comment: What is this.. I don't even..

Answer (score 3):

Make it global.

```
def start():
  global b
  class b(obj):
    pass
```

Comment: Just because you *can* do it, don't assume it's ever a good idea.